# Arris Gateway only allowing 1 device internet access on 2.4Ghz network, but 5ghz seems fine

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, gateway

I've got an Arris TG2472G combo unit from the ISP. I was having issues with it and a Netgear router in bridge mode.  Long story short, I ended up removing the Netgear router for now and did a hard reset of the Arris unit.

So now I feel almost out of the woods, but when I went to connect another phone and laptop to the 2.4ghz network, they get no internet access. Only the first laptop I connected to it seems to be able to get out to the internet on the 2.4ghz. Unfortunately, we will have users with devices only capable of getting on the 2.4ghz.

The 5ghz network seems to be running without issue. I've connected multiple devices and everything seems great.

On the router config, under the LAN tab, RoutedWithNat is currently selected and applied. The other two options there were Bridge and RoutedWithoutNAT.

Comment: Can the second laptop you connect reach the router?

Answer (score 0):

Seem to remember seeing a post about misconfigured radio frequency-band settings causing this kind of issue.  You might want to check that the correct bands a/b/g/ac, etc. are correctly enabled on the unit and configured properly for the 2.4Ghz spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this particular device felt a bit odd to me. It would come up after a restart and make both networks available and I could connect to them, but no internet. Then about a minute later, it would go back offline, take the networks down, and come back up with internet available on both networks, almost like an extra reboot? I've typically only worked with separate modems/routers so maybe this is common behavior.

I was able to solve the 2.4GHz issue by looking at the client list and noticing that one laptop (the one getting internet access) was connected immediately when the network came up during it's second cycle (possibly during the first too? Didn't check in time). I turned the wifi off on that laptop and let the unit do a full restart again and everything worked as expected.

So my theory is that this laptop was somehow able to grab a hold of the WAN IP meant for the router (possibly due to the weird two cycle bootup), hence only the one laptop getting internet access. I'm not an expert here, but this solution was able to resolve the issue.